# Matching different columns and combine them using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two text files.

The first is a space seperated list:

```
23 dog 4
24 cat 5
28 cow 7
```

The second is a `'|'`-separated list:

```
?dog|parallel|numbering|position
Dogsarebarking
?cat|parallel|nuucers|position
CatisBeautiful
```

I want to get an output file like the following:

```
?dog|paralle|numbering|position|23
?cat|parallel|nuucers|position|24
```

It's a `'|'`-separated list containing the values of the second file appended with the value from the first column of the first file where the values in the second column of both files match.

Comment: looks like a JOIN on the second column

Comment: .. wait, what?  Where did all these lines without pipes come from?

Comment: I my huge data set of different animal's files , and only one text file contain data like this , so i want to handle it seprately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `csv` to read the first file, and a dictionary to store the file1 rows. The second file is in FASTA format, so we only take the lines starting with `?`:

```
import csv

with open('file1', 'rb') as file1:
    file1_data = dict(line.split(None, 2)[1::-1] for line in file1 if line.strip())

with open('file2', 'rb') as file2, open('output', 'wb') as outputfile:
    output = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter='|')
    for line in file2:
        if line[:1] == '?':
            row = line.strip().split('|')
            key = row[0][1:]
            if key in file1_data:
                 output.writerow(row + [file1_data[key]])
```

This produces:

```
?dog|parallel|numbering|position|23
?cat|parallel|nuucers|position|24
```

for your input example.

Comment: Looks like he wants to use the first file as a mapping, not just zip them together.

Comment: @MartijnPieters he is using file handling , so output should be in output text file , well +1 for answer

Comment: @MartijnPieters the code you load before works fine thanks , but this have error  `file1_data = {row[1]: row[0] for row in reader1}
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @MartijnPieters i have some line like this `paralle|dog|numbering|positionsdsadfasdasd` so after output it put `23` after `paralle|dog|numbering|positionsdsadfasdasd23` 23 should be after position

Comment: @Angel: Switched to just reading the text file as text and splitting on whitespace, with a empty line check.

Comment: `if row[1] in file1_data:
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @Angel: empty lines in your second input file; I've added a guard.

Comment: no , there are new lines , no empty line  , still not working

Comment: @Angel: Okay, then there are lines with no `|` marker on the line.

Comment: @Angel: added a test to make sure the row is long enough to *have* a `row[1]`, skipping shorter rows.

Comment: @MartijnPieters output is empty file , leeme update my question

Comment: @Angel: Then your `row[1]` columns never matched any data in the `file1_data` mapping. Did you see I tweaked the `file1_data` loading a little?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Did update make anysense ? We can search only for line which start with `?`

Comment: @Angel: it makes sense, that is not a CSV file. We can alter the file loop to not use the CSV module for *input*. That is a FASTA file you have, btw.

Comment: `line.startswith("?")`?   Although reimplementing parts of biopython seems a little silly to begin with, now that we see the format.. :-/

Comment: @DSM: A slice with `[:1]` is a lot faster, works fine too. 3 times as fast, actually.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: when there's a specifically named method for something, I almost always use it in preference to the alternatives.  And I'd *definitely* never worry about performance for something like this.  Styles vary, of course.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but the output text file is still empty

Comment: @Angel: Can you doublecheck the keys of `file1_data` make sense? `print file1_data` if not too large; it seems there are *no* matches between your two files.

Comment: @Angel: Then the next step is to add a `print repr(row[1]), row[1] in file1_data` just before the `if row[1] in file1_data` line to see what is going on. Anything look funny or off?

Comment: `if row[1] in file1_data:` here is the problem , because before this , it prints the rows fine

Comment: @Angel: That is why I asked you to add a `print` statement. The `if` statement fails to find a match in the dictionary. Mind coming to the [python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) so we can diagnose it better?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i select your answer as correct , actually mistake is in my dataset as i update my question , kindly update your answer, 2nd column of first txt file should match the 1st column of second txt file, and than display tha column zero of first text to the end of line of 2nd text file

Comment: but still the output file is empty

Comment: @Angel: That's because `row[0]` includes the `?` at the start. Adjusted the code. You need to be clearer in your input and output to get answers faster next time. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is the sort of task at which the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) library excels:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("c1.txt", sep="|", header=None).dropna()
df2 = pd.read_csv("c2.txt", sep=" ", header=None)
merged = df1.merge(df2, on=1).ix[:,:-1]
merged.to_csv("merged.csv", sep="|", header=None, index=None)
```

---

Some explanation follows.  First we read in the files, into objects called DataFrames:

```
>>> df1 = pd.read_csv("c1.txt", sep="|", header=None).dropna()
>>> df1
               0      1          2         3
0      ?parallel    dog  numbering  position
3      ?parallel    cat    nuucers  position
6  ?non parallel  honey  numbering  position
>>> df2 = pd.read_csv("c2.txt", sep=" ", header=None)
>>> df2
    0    1  2
0  23  dog  4
1  24  cat  5
2  28  cow  7
```

The `.dropna()` skips the cases where there isn't any data.  Alternatively, `df1 = df1[df1[0].str.startswith("?")]` would have been another way to go.

Then we merge them on the first column:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, on=1)
         0_x    1        2_x         3  0_y  2_y
0  ?parallel  dog  numbering  position   23    4
1  ?parallel  cat    nuucers  position   24    5
```

We don't need that last column, so we slice it:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, on=1).ix[:,:-1]
         0_x    1        2_x         3  0_y
0  ?parallel  dog  numbering  position   23
1  ?parallel  cat    nuucers  position   24
```

and then we write it out using `to_csv`, producing:

```
>>> !cat merged.csv
?parallel|dog|numbering|position|23
?parallel|cat|nuucers|position|24
```

Now, for lots of simple tasks, `pandas` can be overkill, and it's important to learn how to use lower-level tools like the `csv` module as well.  OTOH, when you just want something done Right Now(tm), it's very, very handy.

Comment: I must conclude, pandas is rather awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be exactly what a [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_join#Inner_join) is for in a relational database.

> An inner join is the most common join operation used in applications and can be regarded as the default join-type. Inner join creates a new result table by combining column values of two tables (A and B) based upon the join-predicate. The query compares each row of A with each row of B to find all pairs of rows which satisfy the join-predicate. When the join-predicate is satisfied, column values for each matched pair of rows of A and B are combined into a result row.

Have a look at this example:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')

# get hands on the database
c = conn.cursor()

# create and populate table1
c.execute("DROP TABLE table1")
c.execute("CREATE TABLE table1 (col1 text, col2 text, col3 text)")
with open("file1") as f:
    for line in f:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (?, ?, ?)", line.strip().split())

# create table2
c.execute("DROP TABLE table2")
c.execute("CREATE TABLE table2 (col1 text, col2 text, col3 text, col4 text)")
with open("file2") as f:
    for line in f:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", 
            line.strip().split('|'))

# make changes persistent
conn.commit()

# retrieve desired data and write it to file
with open("file3", "w+") as f:
    for x in c.execute(
        """
        SELECT table2.col1
             , table2.col2
             , table2.col3
             , table2.col4
             , table1.col1 
        FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.col2 = table2.col2
        """):
        f.write("%s\n" % "|".join(x))

# close connection
conn.close()
```

The output file would look like this:

```
paralle|dog|numbering|position|23
parallel|cat|nuucers|position|24
```